# -OR- text displayed under paypal checkout after removing CC checkout options

Tags: checkout, paypal

I've disabled all payment options except Paypal, however on the checkout page an "-OR-" text is still visible beneath the Paypal checkout button (see pic) on the checkout page.

Does anybody know why this is happening, and how it can be fixed?[image: enter link description here]

Comment: See in the page source if "Paypal - Bill me later" is trying to load at that place. If not, then try reverting to base theme temporarily to see if this has something to do with the theme.

Comment: Paypal bill me later doesn't appear to be trying to load. This is what I see in the page source;

<li>
    <p class="paypal-logo">
    <span class="paypal-or">-OR-</span>
    </p>
</li>

I am trying to only have the Checkout with paypal button available on my website as I'm not looking to take credit card, or other payments.

Comment: Then check reverting to the base theme temporarily. See if that fixes the problem.